# Consistent and rigorous definitions of curve, arc and path

Tags: differential-geometry

While reading many books, textbooks or Internet and actually I'm getting very much confused about the issues related to definitions of arcs, curves, paths, their parametrizations and curve images. Is there any consistent (and rigorous) way to define all these terms? Perhaps some of them are not needed actually or mean essentially the same. The parametrization is related to orientation and thus for me better fits the term "path" having starting and ending points. Term "curve" would mean some set with no orientation given. But still, I'm a bit confused...

Many thanks,

Radek

Comment: Consistent - probably not, there are a lot of conflicting definitions people use, but they are usually always rigourously definable.

Comment: path in a space $X$: start with the concept of **homeomorphism** from a connected $I\subseteq{\Bbb R}$ to $X$.